Destructor for library object ends up in binary
I have a closed source binary with debug symbols compiled against QT 5.3.2. I tried to run it on Debian Bookworm, using the QT version in the repository (5.15.8). It starts up but crashes with a segmentation fault. I then used gdb and IDA to figure out what was going on, and for some reason the destructor QDebug::~QDebug is included in the binary, while the constructor is called from the imported QMessageLogger::debug. During the destructor, there is a null pointer accessed.
I have never seen something like this before, so I am wondering: How can the destructor of a library suddenly end up in the main binary? I assume the only way to fix it would be to compile the matching QT version, so the destructor uses the correct addresses/offsets within the object?

Methods defined in a class body are inline and may generate code in every translation unit where they are included.  This can lead to ABI issues when building with different versions.

@RichardCritten But then QT breaks their "compatibility promise" which states: New Qt 5 minor releases will not break binary compatibility, and patch level releases are forward and backward compatible. Effectively this is not binary compatible, as this is a  new "minor release" and it did break binary compatibility?
